# Good morning/Afternoon ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Just wondering if there is any ampscript function to work out if it morning or afternoon as I would like to greet people with morning or afternoon using local time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [datediff()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/#DateDiff) function is your friend.  It's pretty tolerant to all kinds of dates and times.  You can comment/uncomment the `set @now` lines to suit your testing needs.

```
%%[

  var @now, @hourdiff
  set @now = now()
  set @now = "10:00 PM"
  set @now = "6:01 AM"
  set @now = "13:01"
  set @hourdiff = datediff("00:00",@now,"H")

  set @greeting = ""
  if @hourdiff >= 0 and @hourdiff <= 12 then
    set @greeting = "Good Morning!"
  elseif @hourdiff > 12 and @hourdiff <= 17 then
    set @greeting = "Good Afternoon!"
  else
    set @greeting = "Good Evening!"
  endif


]%%
now(): %%=now()=%%
<br>@hourdiff: %%=v(@hourdiff)=%%
<br>@greeting: %%=v(@greeting)=%%
```

**Output:**

```
now(): 7/2/2015 1:22:07 PM 
@hourdiff: 13 
@greeting: Good Afternoon!
```

Comment: Thanks will test this out. Guess this will be set at point of send and not at time of opening the email

Comment: Correct.  This is all processed server-side at the time of send.  So, the time of day the email is sent will not necessary be the same time of day the email is opened.

Comment: can the now() be set to local time ie UK as it's displaying the US time

Comment: Now() always returns the current date time from the SFMC data center.  S1=US/Central, S4=US/Central, S6=US/Mountain.  You'll need to offset it accordingly.  You can determine the data center from your SFMC URL.  If it doesn't contain S4 or S6, it's S1.

Comment: OK thanks, sorted it by using dateadd +7. just need to find away to calculate it when the clocks go forward/backwards as it will be +6 or +7

Comment: Thanks, have sorted the time difference. thanks for your help